# Adding external user to sharepoint 2013 programmitically

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

It says here --  http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/160998.aspx that sharepoint external users cant be created programmitically.

Is it possible to use rest API to programmitically add external users to my sharepoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the given article:

> There is no such feature for SharePoint Online to invite external
>   users to a site automatically, and to programmatically invite external
>   users, it is not possible. The reason is that SharePoint Online
>   creates a unique invitation id per invitation, and each invitation can
>   only be accepted once. Based on my understanding, it is impossible to
>   get a random and unique invitation id created by SharePoint Online.

There is no REST API to programmatically add External users as of now.

May be in future release they can add that support. But as of now, unfortunately there is no way.